# How to manage background tasks iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

Lets say a user starts async request in `PageViewController` flow then dismisses. If they quickly bring back `PageViewController` it won't navigate to the correct page because an async request (that determines the next logical page to show) is underway. Is it standard to prevent the user from dismissing controller or asking them not to? If not, how do I manage background tasks, so I know to keep loading screen up and wait to navigate pages until last request completes and changes state/server side data?

Comment: You could "block" navigation by preventing user interaction or disabling normal navigation elements or use some kind of full screen "hud", which overlays the current context (think dialog box) which shows "work in progress" or some other similar idea ... if I understand correctly

Comment: Are there any methods to force cancel the async request when the pageviewcontroller gets dismissed? If not, there should be ways to disable interaction while a request is being processed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll also take this as a confirmation that its not bad practice to hold user hostage on screen while request is ongoing. I cant think of how other apps handle this. Ill just disable user interaction.

Comment: @jackw11111 Using `NSURLSession` so I'm sure there is a way. Just don't know the API well enough to say off the top. Perhaps queues would come into play here?

Comment: Yes, I agree with MadProgrammer, dialogbox with dark transparent overlay and a loading wheel, 'please wait...', etc, cancelling request could be sluggish.

Comment: I'm sure there is in docs. Have you looked into notificationcenter and observers?

Comment: Not enough if thats where you cancel requests.